# How do i create a list of lines until a word is in the line, then start a new list of lines again until a word

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that has lines of coordinates

```
L1A  10.73  -36.14
L1B  15.30  -54.70
Segment
L2A  17.03  -43.80
L2B  17.90  -49.55
L4A  03.00  -54.00
Segment
L3A  07.80  -36.00
L3B  03.00  -36.00
```

What i want to do is for the lines between the word Segment i want to create a list

So L1A and L1B would be one list, L2A L2B L4A would be a second list, etc...

So how do i create a loop or something so that it appends a list until it reaches the word 'Segment', then it opens a new list and appends until the next word 'Segment' and so forth.

The first list would be named coords1, second coords2,.... coordsn

This is what i have, but this will just keep updating "coords", instead of stopping at 'Segment" and open a new coords list...

```
coord = []
with open('kml_coastrica.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not 'Segment' in line:
            newline = line.split('  ')
            lon = int(newline[1])
            lat = int(newline[2])
            coords.append([lat,lon])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you append inner lists to the same list all the time - you need one level of nesting *more*:

1. Create a list of lists,
2. iterate your line of files,

   1. split line into coords (I thing you mixed them up order wise, please check)
   2. add each coord to a list
3. add each line-list to the last inner list of your results
4. if you hit a new `'Segment'` - add a new inner list to your results
5. continue until done:

*Create file:*

```
with open("t.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""L1A  10.73  -36.14
L1B  15.30  -54.70
Segment
L2A  17.03  -43.80
L2B  17.90  -49.55
L4A  03.00  -54.00
Segment
L3A  07.80  -36.00
L3B  03.00  -36.00
""")
```

*Process file:*

```
result = [[]]                 # start with an empty inner list
with open("t.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "Segment":
            result.append([])           # add new empty list at end
        else:
            data = line.strip().split()
            lon = float(data[1])        # you need floats - not int's
            lat = float(data[2])        # same here: floats

            # add data point to last inner list
            result[-1].append([lat,lon]) # I think you got them mixed here ?

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[[-36.14, 10.73], [-54.7, 15.3]], 
 [[-43.8, 17.03], [-49.55, 17.9], 
  [-54.0, 3.0]], [[-36.0, 7.8], [-36.0, 3.0]]]
```

In case your data stops with a `'Segment'` your last list element will be empty.

Comment: how can i make it so the output is like this instead...      [[(-36.14, 10.73), (-54.7, 15.3)], 
 [(-43.8, 17.03), (-49.55, 17.9), 
  (-54.0, 3.0)], [(-36.0, 7.8), (-36.0, 3.0)]]

Comment: You add your coordinates inside a tuple instead of a list: `result[-1].append( (lat,lon) )` ... this might help:  [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)  and [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)